# How to efficiently display text instead of null when binding in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, data-binding, null-coalescing

In the following code `site` can be null, but if it is there, then `company` will not be null. How can I *efficiently* display a "-" when the `site` is null that scales well for 1000's of these rows?

```
<tr v-for="obj in objs" :key="obj.id">
  <td>{{obj.site.company.name || "-"}}</td> <!-- does not work -->
</tr>
```

I can make a method to do this:

```
methods: {
  handleNulls(obj) {
    // logic
    return "-";
  }
}
```

But it would be nicer if it could be done inline, or using a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<tr v-for="obj in objs" :key="obj.id">
  <td v-if="obj.site !== null">{{obj.site.company.name}}</td>
  <td v-else>-</td>
</tr>
```

[Documentation - conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an inline `if`. You should check whether site is `undefined` and whether company is `undefined`:

```
<tr v-for="obj in objs" :key="obj.id">
  <td>{{obj.site && obj.site.company ? obj.site.company.name : '-'}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to show "-" if the site is not available so I did this : (the first element of the array is null)

```js
let app;


function appInit(){
 app = new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data:{
   obj:[
    null,
    {site:{company:{name:"test2"}}},
    {site:{company:{name:"test3"}}}
   ]
  }
 });
}

appInit();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in obj">{{item && item.site && item.site.company&& item.site.company.name ? item.site.company.name : " - "}}
    </li>
  <ul>
<div>
```